# Equivalence of defining neighborhood as an open set or as a closed set in a special case

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, continuity, convex-analysis

Let continuous $f:X\to\mathbb R$. $X$ is an interval of $\mathbb R$.

Are the following two statements equivalent?

1) For almost every $x\in X$ $\exists$ open interval (neighborhood) $I\ni x$ s.t. $f$ is either locally convex or locally concave on $I$. (i.e. only countable number of $x\in X$ does not have such neighborhood).

$f$ is locally convex on $I$ if $\forall x,y\in I$, we have $f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)\leq f(\lambda x)+f((1-\lambda)y)$

(In another word, epi$f(I)$ is a convex set.)

2) $\forall x\in X$ $\exists$ (non-singleton) closed interval $I\ni x$ s.t. $f$ is either locally convex or locally concave over $I$.

If they are equivalent, then, in general, why people tend to use open set rather than closed set to define a neighborhood?

Comment: What do you mean by "locally convex"? Just that $f$ is convex on the corresponding interval?

Comment: @0x539 Thank you very much for the note. You are right. The question is clarified.

Comment: What do you mean by "$X$ is an interval of $\mathbb{R}$"? Can $X$ be any one of $[a,b]$, $[a,b)$, $(a,b)$ or $(a,b]$?

Comment: @user587192 How about this? For simplicity let's just consider the compact case at first.

Comment: The word "locally" is redundant: your condition says that $f$ *is* convex on $I$.

Comment: @user587192 Indeed, your statement is more concise and clear.

Comment: @HighGPA people usually mean something else when they say "almost every"

Comment: @HighGPA also, meaning "open set" when saying "neighborhood" is a more general topological phenomenon. You shouldn't live in such a convexity-centric world.

Comment: @mathworker21 The specific case will help me understand the situation. I agree with you overall. I will edit the question to be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2\Rightarrow 1$. Without loss of generality we can assume that $X$ is an open subset of $\Bbb R$. Let $X_{conv}$ (resp. $X_{conc}$) bet a set of all $x\in X$ such that there exists an open interval $I\ni x$ s.t. $f$ is locally convex (resp. locally concave) over $I$. Assume to the contrary that (1) does not hold, that is a set $X’=X\setminus(X_{conv}\cup X_{conc})$ is uncountable. For a natural $n$ we call a point $x\in X’$ an *$\frac 1n$-corner* provided 
$(x-\frac 1n,x)\cap X’=\varnothing$ or $(x,x+\frac 1n)\cap X’=\varnothing$. It is easy to check that among any three distinct $\frac 1n$-corners we can find two with the distance between them bigger than $\frac 1n$. This implies that the set of  $\frac 1n$-corners is countable, so there exists a point $x\in X’$ which is not an $\frac 1n$-corner for any natural $n$. By (2), there exists a (non-singleton) closed interval $I’\ni x$ s.t. $f$ is either locally convex or locally concave over $I’$. Then $f$ is either locally convex or locally concave over an open interval $I=\operatorname{int} I’$. But $X’\cap I\ne\varnothing$, a contradiction.

$1\not\Rightarrow 2$. Define a function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ as follows. Put $ f(x)=0$, if $x=0$ or $x=\frac 1{2n}$, with $n\in\Bbb Z\setminus\{0\}$ or $|x|\ge 1$. For $k\in\Bbb N\cup{0}$ put $ f\left(\pm\frac 1{4k+1}\right)= \frac 1{4k+1}$ and $ f\left(\pm\frac 1{4k+3}\right)=-\frac 1{4k+3}$. Extend $ f(x)$ piesewise-linearly to the remaining $x\in\Bbb R$. Since $f$ is linear at $\Bbb R$ but a countable closed set, it satifies (1). On the other hand, on any open interval $I\ni 0$, $f$ has countably infinite many zeros, so $f$ is neither convex, nor concave on $I$.

---

> why people tend to use open set rather than closed set to define a neighborhood?

I don’t see a relation of this with the previous. For me a choice to work with open or closed neighborhoods usually is a matter of convenience. Maybe, to work with open neighborhoods 
is often more convenient than with closed these.

By the way, a closed interval containing $x$ is not its neighborhood, because a neighborhood of $x$ must contain $x$ in its interior.